# How can I troubleshoot the lack of detection of the D-Link DWM-152 (HSDPA USB modem)?

Tags: 10.04, modem

I just installed Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

However, my D-Link DWM-152 (HSDPA USB modem) is not able to be detected.

I am having exactly same result as c_siswan
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1476983

Can anyone suggest me a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to www.dlink.com, support+download and then search for DWM-152 and update your firmware. Have a look at this Blogpost saylinux.wordpress.com/2010/07/20/using-d-link-3g-usb-dwm-152-with-ubuntu-10-04/

Maybe it works with network-manager if you try the newest developer version from here: https://launchpad.net/~network-manager/+archive/trunk

Comment: Works pretty well. I am happy.

Answer (score 1):

Give [sakis3g](http://www.sakis3g.org/) a try. If it works than we know the modem works on Ubuntu and it's just a matter of including it in usb_modeswitch data or toggling it manually and we can work towards that.

Comment: Thanks. But not working for my case.